# Failed prop type: The prop `address` is marked as required in `UpdateAddress`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, react-redux, rest

here i am getting addresses array in a reduxdevtools but not address object
in a backend api is working fine with postman and getting desired result but
for front end it is not working. Getting error like --TypeError: Cannot
destructure property 'id' of 'nextProps.address' as it is undefined.

**addressReducers.js:**

```
   const initialState={
      addresses:[],
       address:{}
     };
  export default function(state=initialState,action){
        switch(action.type){
    
        case GET_ADDRESS :
            return{
                ...state,
                address:action.payload
                  };

            
        **addressAction.js:**
                    export const getAddress=(id,history)=> async dispatch => 
              {
               try{
                     const res= axios.get(`/api/user/address/${id}`)
                   dispatch({
                      type:GET_ADDRESS,
                      payload:res.data
                   });
                     }catch(error){
                  history.push("/dashboard")
                  }
                 };
                 **UpdateAddress.js:**
                          class UpdateAddress extends Component{
                  constructor(){
                     super();
                      this.state={
                      id: "",
                      addressLine1:"" ,
                      addressLine2:"" ,
                      userName: "",
                      contactNo: "",
                      postalCode: "",
                     acceptanceCriteria: "",
                     uniqueId: "",
                     errors:{}
                     };
                     this.onChange=this.onChange.bind(this);
                     this.onSubmit=this.onSubmit.bind(this);
                     }
                     componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
                     if(nextProps.errors){
                     this.setState({errors:nextProps.errors})
                          }
                          const{
                                id ,
                                addressLine1 ,
                                addressLine2 ,
                                userName ,
                                contactNo ,
                                postalCode ,
                                acceptanceCriteria ,
                                uniqueId 
                                            }=nextProps.address
                                   this.setState({
                                   id ,
                                addressLine1 ,
                                addressLine2 ,
                                userName ,
                                contactNo ,
                                postalCode ,
                                acceptanceCriteria ,
                                uniqueId
                              });
                              }
                       componentDidMount() {
                  //const {address}= this.state;
                       const {id}=this.props.match.params;
                       this.props.getAddress(id, this.props.history)
                                                 }
                       onChange(e){
                         this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value});
                              }
                        onSubmit(e){
                             e.preventDefault()
                             const updateAddress={
                             "id": this.state.id,
                             "addressLine1": this.state.addressLine1,
                             "addressLine2": this.state.addressLine2,
                             "userName": this.state.userName,
                             "contactNo": this.state.contactNo,
                             "postalCode": this.state.postalCode,
                             "acceptanceCriteria": 
                                              this.state.acceptanceCriteria,
                             "uniqueId": this.state.uniqueId

                                      };



              this.props.createAddress(updateAddress,this.props.history);
}

            render(){
                  const {errors}=this.state;

                  return (
                           )

                    }
                   UpdateAddress.propTypes={
                         getAddress:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
                         createAddress:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
                         address:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
                         errors:PropTypes.object.isRequired
                          }
                 const  mapStateToProps = state =>({
                   address:state.address.address,
                   errors:state.errors

                 });
                export default connect(mapStateToProps, 
                      {getAddress,createAddress})(UpdateAddress);
                     //console.error
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your getAddress function in addressAction.js, you need to return a async function.

```
export const getAddress= (id,history)=>  return async dispatch => {
              
        try {
            const res= axios.get(`/api/user/address/${id}`)
            dispatch({
                      type:GET_ADDRESS,
                      payload:res.data
                    });
             } catch(error){
                      history.push("/dashboard")
             }
            };
}
```

Comment: @ Peter Petrovic while adding return keyword it is showing error and even not compiling -------> ./src/actions/addressAction.js
  Line 30:40:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  28 | 
  29 | };
> 30 | export const getAddress=(id,history)=> return  async dispatch =>{
     |                                        ^
  31 |     try{
  32 |     const res= axios.get(`/api/user/address/${id}`)
  33 |     dispatch({